# Исключение по шаблону регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Для номера PBK1234567890, нужно составить шаблон регулярки, чтобы добавлять в начало 7, если номер не начинается с PBK и состоит из 10 цифр (т.е 1234567890), то в начало добавить 7 (должно получиться 71234567890). Но не добавлять 7 если номер начинается с PBK.
Составил шаблон, но не могу довести до конца логику (связка И для двух групп не получается и возможно выражение НЕ начинается не верно): s/^(?!PBX)(\d{10,})/7$2/g

Comment: А зачем условие на PBX, если основное условие на 10 цифр и так не сработает если строка начнется не с 10 цифр. т.е. просто `s/^(\d{10,})/7$1/` и кстати зачем в конце `g` ?

Comment: А ну да логично. Типа match. спасибо за подсказку. g это вроде global получается.

Comment: Да, `g` это global, что бы произвести в строке несколько замен. Но у вас замена привязана к началу строки т.е. может быть всего одна, так что он не нужен. Я просто увидев его заподозрил, что возможно все сложнее ...

Answer (score 0):

Шаблон регулярного выражения:   s/^(\d{10})$/7$1/